# How to Inject a Object into a Fragment, provided by Activity

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

Using dagger.android, how can I achieve this:

where the Object is like this: `ObjectA(Activity activity){...}`

```
ActivityModule
- @Binds abstract provideObjectA(Activity activity)

Activity
- @Inject ObjectA objectA;
```

This works good, and I understand it. But what can I do when the Activity hosts a fragment, and that fragment and it's module also needs access to the same instance of ObjectA?

Say, there is an ObjectB that requires an ObjectA, and the Fragment wants to provide ObjectB.

```
ObjectB(ObjectA objA){...}
```

.

```
FragmentModule 
- @Provides ObjectB() { return new ObjectB( ??? ) }
```

As you can see, ObjectB needs ObjectA, which is provided in the ActivityModule. How can the FragmentModule get access to ObjectA, the same one that was provided in ActivityModule?

I am providing the fragment using ContributesAndroidInjector, from the newest dagger.android

Comment: Is your Fragment component a subcomponent of your Activity component?

Comment: No I am not using components with android.dagger, but I found that providing the fragment within the activity module fixed the problem, and the fragment has access to all the activity dependencies.